# CreateUserWizard automatically login newly created users

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, createuserwizard, anonymous-users

I am using CreateUserWizard control in my asp.net application. I want to create an anonymous user in sql server database. I want to see IsAnonymous column's value true, but what happens is as soon as I click the button "create user", immediately the newly created user log's in into the system and it's IsAnonymous column becomes false. I have used the property LoginCreatedUser = false, but it does not work. still the new user automatically logs in. What should I do, so that CreateUserWizard will create the Anonymous user and login control will make it authenticated.

I am first creating CreateUserWizard control in my aspx file, and when I click the "create user" button user logs in automatically, which is not my requirement. I am sorry if many of you will consider it as a duplicate question but honestly no answer solved my problem.
thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not aware that you can create a anonymous user in your authentication table, since then that would require the user to logon, and then by logic that user not anonymous anymore, but represent a logged on user with some flag you decided to cook up that says they are anonymous when in fact they are not, right? Anonymous means the user did not HAVE to logon, and thus by computer logic means they are anonymous by this fact. Unless you telling me that the user MUST logon first, and they you want them to have a anonymous role? again: anonymous means they don't exist in your user table.

Comment: So there is no answer to your question because you asking how to create a user in a table that means the user not anonymous anymore. Your question is illogical.